# Parse CSV file with commas in some columns Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a file with the below example lines:

```
(22642441022L, u'<a href="http://example.com">Click</a>', u'fox, dog, cat are examples http://example.com')
(1153634043, u'<a href="http://example.com">Click</a>', u"I learned so much from my mistakes, I think I'm gonna make some more")
```

I'm trying to parse it to a list of objects with this code:

```
import csv

file_path = 'Data/example.txt'
data = []

with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in reader:
        data.append({'id' : row[0], 'source' : row[1], 'content' : row[2]})
```

As expected, the content is truncated due to the ',' in the content column.
Is there any package that can help me parse this out of the box?

Comment: Does the file actually contain `(` and `u'` ?

Comment: Does the file look _exactly_ like this?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. I don't know which language was used to write such a file, but it's a dataset I need to load

Comment: You can't parse this code with python3. Your numbers have the Long `L` suffix at the end. My guess is someone foolishly `str`d a list of tuples into a file using python2. Please kick them.

Comment: That looks like a pure python `print` of a list of tuples... Eval comes to mind, although is probably not such a great idea (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Comment: `[x.strip("""()"'""") for x in line.split(', u')]` but I don't know what to do with `L` if it's  a problem

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I wish I could, but it's a dataset available as is.

Comment: I don't really care about the numbers here (I can deal with them as strings), my problem is parsing columns correctly as strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your data, someone has dumped the `str` version of a list into a file as-is, using python2.

One thing's for sure - you can't use a CSV reader for this data. You can't even use a JSON parser (which would've been the next best thing).

What you can do, is use `ast.literal_eval`. With python2, this works out of the box.

```
import ast

data = []
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            data.append(ast.literal_eval(line))
        except (SyntaxError, ValueError):
            pass
```

`data` should look something like this -

```
[(22642441022L,
  '<a href="http://example.com">Click</a>',
  'fox, dog, cat are examples http://example.com'),
 (1153634043,
  '<a href="http://example.com">Click</a>',
  "I learned so much from my mistakes, I think I'm gonna make some more")]
```

You can then pass `data` into a `DataFrame` as-is -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df

             A                                       B  \
0  22642441022  <a href="http://example.com">Click</a>   
1   1153634043  <a href="http://example.com">Click</a>   

                                                   C  
0      fox, dog, cat are examples http://example.com  
1  I learned so much from my mistakes, I think I'...
```

---

If you want this to work with python3, you'll need to get rid of the long suffix `L`, and the unicode prefix `u`. You might be able to do this using `re.sub` from the `re` module.

```
import re
```

```
for line in f:
    try:
        i = re.sub('(\d+)L', r'\1', line)       # remove L suffix
        j = re.sub('(?<=,\s)u(?=\')', '', i)    # remove u prefix
        data.append(ast.literal_eval(j))
    except (SyntaxError, ValueError):
        pass
```

Notice the added `re.sub('(\d+)L', r'\1', line)`, which removes the `L` suffix at the end of a string of digits.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but it didn't work. It throws syntax error at all lines. I'm using python 3.6 BTW.

Comment: @MokhtarAshour If you could show me one of the lines that are erroring out, that would help... because, it works for the data you posted ;-(

Comment: (22642586115L, 7248952, 1283282654000L, 0, -1, -1, None, -999999.0, -999999.0, u'<a href="http://www.example.com/" rel="nofollow">Ping.fm</a>', 0, 0, u'CPPRI Recruitment 2010 at http://example.com/', -1, u'', u'')

Comment: @MokhtarAshour Weird that `ast` sometimes parses unicode, and sometimes not. This would've worked on python2, but I'll need regex to get rid of the unicodes. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @MokhtarAshour Edits made, try it now and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like the file was generated doing something like this (a pure dump of a Python `str()` or `print`):

```
data_list = [
    (22642441022L, u'<a href="http://example.com">Click</a>', u'fox, dog, cat are examples http://example.com'),
    (1153634043, u'<a href="http://example.com">Click</a>', u"I learned so much from my mistakes, I think I'm gonna make some more")
]  # List of tuples

with open('./stack_084.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join([str(data) for data in data_list]))
```

Regular expressions come to mind (assuming that the values on your second "column") **always** start with `<a` and end with `a>`:

```
import pprint
import re

line_re = re.compile(
    r'\('
    r'(?P<num>\d+)L{0,1}.'
    r'+?'
    r'[\'\"](?P<source>\<a.+?a\>)[\"\']'
    r'.+?'
    r'[\'\"](?P<content>.+?)[\"\']'
    r'\)'
)

data = []
with open('./stack_084.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = line_re.match(line)
        if match:
            data.append({
                'id': int(match.groupdict()['num']),
                'source': match.groupdict()['source'],
                'content': match.groupdict()['content']
            })

# You should see parsed data here:
print(pprint.pformat(data))
```

This outputs:

```
[{'content': 'fox, dog, cat are examples http://example.com',
  'id': 22642441022,
  'source': '<a href="http://example.com">Click</a>'},
 {'content': "I learned so much from my mistakes, I think I'm gonna make some "
             'more',
  'id': 1153634043,
  'source': '<a href="http://example.com">Click</a>'}]
```

Comment: I see you use Regex to handle it, but the actual lines in the file are longer (I included a subset). This is one line of the real dataset : 
 
(22642586115L, 7248952, 1283282654000L, 0, -1, -1, None, -999999.0, -999999.0, u'<a href="example.com/"; rel="nofollow">Ping.fm</a>', 0, 0, u'CPPRI Recruitment 2010 at example.com/';, -1, u'', u'') This way I will need carefully to write a REGEX that handles the whole line

Comment: Numbers are easy... Just more of the `(\d+)L{0,1}` groups... And those `None`... Those are suspicious. I imagine you have rows where the 7th value is not `None`? (I don't imagine that whatever generated your data is gonna have **ALL** `None`(s), right?)

Comment: Yes, some rows contain something like u'MyComfyCat'

Comment: I have accepted the first answer, still like your answer though. so I'm up voting